# Turn sentence to predicat formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am to write this senten "I have read atleast 2 books" into formula of predicat logic where C(x) = i have read x;

The only thing i can think of is

$(\exists x)\wedge (\exists y)(C(x) \wedge C(y)\wedge (\forall z)(('(z=x)\wedge '(z=y))\Rightarrow (C(z)\vee 'C(z)))$

but in this there could be a state , when i havent read any of Z and that would mean i have read only two books , what is the right formula for this kind of sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't write $\land$ between two quantifiers: it's not well-formed. Not to mention that primes are never written over logical connectives ($\land'$, for example, occurs in no well-formed formula of first order logic).

In logic-like English, what you want to express is: there are books $x,y$ such that I have read $x$ and I have read $y$ and $x\ne y$. Symbolically:
$$
\exists x \,\exists y\,(C(x) \land C(y) \land x\ne y)
$$
*Added in response to question in comments*

The above formula says that $x,y$ are distinct books I have read — so there are at least two. In order to express that there are also at most two, you have to conjoin another clause saying that any book I have read is either $x$ or $y$. The formula for "I have read exactly two books" is therefore:
$$
\exists x \,\exists y\,[(C(x) \land C(y) \land x\ne y) \land \forall z\,(C(z)\to (z=y\lor z=x))]
$$

Comment: sorry , the negation should have been on conjucution.. but wouldnt your formula mean that i have read 2 books , nothing more , nothing less?

Comment: @trolkura No, the formula is true whenever you've read at least two books. For example, if you've read all three books of C. S. Lewis's space trilogy, then BrianO's formula is true because you can instantiate $x$ as "Out of the Silent Planet" and $y$ as "Perelandra"; these instantiations make $C(x)$, $C(y)$, and $x\neq y$ true as required.  The fact that you've also read "That Hideous Strength" does no damage to this evaluation of the formula.

Comment: @ OP I totally missed your question, 17 days ago — sorry. I have nothing to add @AndreasBlass 's great reply. Thanks Andreas.

Comment: @AndreasBlass and OP I lied, I do have something to add -- an addendum to the answer.